# Unzip .rar file using command prompt

Tags: cmd

I have a .rar file available and I want to unzip it using cmd, how can I do that?

```
unrar e C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Desktop.rar
```

Comment: Download [unrar for windows](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm)?

Comment: I have winrar installed in my system

Comment: [This](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarw32.exe) should do it if you are on windows

Comment: Still it's not working :(

Comment: it's giving error as "C:\Users\anoopn>unrar e "C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Test zip\Desktop.rar"
'unrar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: give it the full path: `"C:\programs\whereever you installed it\unrar" e "...`

Answer (score 2):

1. install unRAR.exe to "C:\programs\wherever installed" from [unrar for windows](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm)
2. in cmd or pwrshell change directory to unrar's directory and run it like below

```html
cd "C:\programs\wherever unrar installed"
./unRAR.exe e "C:\user\unzipthis.rar"
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea from https://cects.com/using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows/

```
@echo off

REM uncompress_rar.bat

REM This uncompresses .rar archives in a folder specified by the user, extracts files to 
the extracted folder and moves the processed archive to the completed folder

setlocal

REM Specify the folder to uncompress below:
REM -------------------------------- Compressed file folder_----------------------------
set dirA=C:\folder_to_uncompress
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


REM Specify the extracted files folder below:
REM -------------------------------- Folder to extract to-------------------------------
set dirE=C:\Extractedfiles\
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


REM Specify where to move processed archives below. This folder must exist:
REM -------------------------------- Processed folder-----------------------------------
set dirC=C:\Processed\
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


REM change to directory
cd %dirA%

REM Path to WinRAR executable in Program Files
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%


echo.
echo All files in %dirA% to be uncompressed
echo.


echo.

FOR %%i IN (*.rar) do (
unrar e "%%~ni.rar" "%dirE%"
move "%%~ni.rar" "%dirC%"
echo completed uncompressing "%%i" and moved archives or archive to "%dirC%"
)
goto eof

:eof

endlocal

echo.
echo "Task Completed"
echo.

@pause
```